# How to use graphql type in other files for relationship without duplication

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to separate all the tables in different directory. However, I am encountering some problems. Look at the ExpenseItem below. ExpenseType is under ExpenseType directory so graphql throws error. In order to solve that I need to add ExpenseType in ExpeseItem/typeDefs which is redundant.

**ExpenseItem/typeDefs**

```
   type ExpenseItem {
        id: ID!
        name: String,
        updatedAt: DateTime,
        expenseType: [ExpenseType]
    }
```

Is there any better way to stitch the schema?

I also tried something like this. However, graphql stop working.
When I query, it does not goes into the resolver, is there anything wrong on setup?

```
const schemas = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: `
    scalar JSON
    scalar DateTime
    type Query {
      test: String
    }
    ${typeDefs1}
    ${typeDefs2}
    ${typeDefs3}
    ${typeDefs4}

  `,
  resolvers: {
    // Type resolvers
    JSON: GraphQLJSON,
    DateTime: GraphQLDateTime,

    // schema resolvers
    ...resolvers1,
    ...resolvers2,
    ...resolvers3,
    ...resolvers4
  }

})

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,

  context: { db }
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot merge your resolvers like this. Using the spread operator to merge an object results in a *shallow merge*. If the merged objects share any common properties (for example, `Query`), only the last merged property will be present in the resulting object. You need to *deep merge* the objects. You can do so yourself, or use something like `lodash`'s `merge`.

Additionally, you can pass an array of strings as the `typeDefs` to `makeExecutableSchema` instead of combining them yourself.

Comment: Ended up passing resolvers in array format [resolver1, resolver 2, {JSON: GraphQLJSON,}]